# $\lim a^x x$ when $x$ approaches $\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

If $|a|<1$, show that

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} a^x x =0$$

L'Hospital's Rule doesn't work, in this case. How can I analyze the given function to conclude this ?

Comment: Given the tags, I assume you mean $0<a<1$.

Comment: L'Hopital works, just note that $a^x x = \frac{x}{a^{-x}}$

Answer (score 7):

If $a=0$, the claim is trivial. Else, define $b=\frac{1}{a}$. Because absolute convergence implies convergence, you might assume $a>0$ so that $b>1$. Now
$$
a^xx=\frac{x}{b^x}
$$
So L'Hospital's Rule actually applies
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}a^xx=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{b^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{b^x\log b}=0.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} a^x x =\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x}{a^{-x}}$$ 
Now use L'Hospital
$$ = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{-a^{-x}\ln a} = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{-a^x}{\ln a} = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

$$xa^x = \frac{x}{\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^x}$$
now apply l'Hospital.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\ln a ^x x = x\ln a +\ln x$. It follows that
$$
\frac{\ln a^xx}{x}\rightarrow \ln a
$$
as $x\rightarrow \infty$. Now consider what happens to $\ln a^xx$ and apply the exponential function.

Comment: I only see an indetermination in thelimit $x lna + lnx$ too. Can you be more specific?

Comment: $\ln x / x$ can be handled by L'Hospital.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

I suggest that you consider the different cases :$a>1$,$a=1$,$a<1$. For the first two cases, the answer seems to be obvious :$\infty$. But the problem is totally different when $a<1$.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just wondering if L'Hospital's Rule works for the anti-derivative. For example, one would like to evaluate

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} a^x x = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{a^x}{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{a^x}{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\int a^xdx}{\int\frac{1}{x}dx}=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\frac{a^x}{\ln a}}{\ln \rvert x\lvert}=0$$
Because the numerator tends to $0$ and the denominator tends to $\infty$, the limit tends to $0$.

Is this valid?